# PHP Script is not working as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to make my own script that verify's the websites url and have tired to add a key that is for extra verification that the user is of my monthly payment clients that use my admin system but since i have add the key to my script it does not work how i want it to, this is my code please note i not added any database connections to it yet

```
<?php

$site ='SITE URL';
$key = '12534';

if($server==$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && $key != $site && $key!=(1245)){
echo 'sorry u do not have the correct permission';
}else{
echo 'correct permission';
}
?>
```

i keep getting sorry u do not have the correct permission

Comment: Has to be one of the worst titles today.

Comment: $key != $site will be true forever !!!

Comment: so how would i changes this so it not always true and sorry for the bad title did not know what to call the title

Comment: Look at the answers. They both address the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo in your code

```
if($server=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && $key != $site && $key)
```

should be

```
if($server==$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && $key != $site && $key)
```

Comment: I would explain the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: i have edited my code in my question and the extra = is now always turiong true

Comment: both condition $key != $site && $key!=(1245) will always true. It would be better to provide more clear code.

Comment: this is most complex thing i done with php i only every used php for databases

Comment: what is the value of $server?

Comment: bulls the value of $server should be the sites url but i think i made the value of $site the url

Answer (score 0):

When - `$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` it will always be `true` as it will assign `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to `$server`. The rest of the conditions are true  for this case.

Try with `$server == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` it will compare the values of the variables.

```
if($server == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && $key != $site && $key){
```

Comment: I would explain the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: i have edited my code for in my question the extra bit of code i added but adding the = is returning always true

Comment: it does if i do not add in the extra = in but if i have == then it always return true i not done anything like this  before and i still am learning about the differents between == and =

Comment: @user3907336 = is assignment operator and == is comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

As just said you have to check that $server is equal to $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] using == and not =. Using only one =, your are assigning the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to $server.

In order to understand better, you can see this example:

```
$a=2;

//assign the value of 3 to $a
if($a=3) {
echo $a;
}
```

It will print 3

Comment: thank you thats helped me out to understand it  and i think i sorted it